# Inserting multiple videos to a playlist using multithreading results in videos missing

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I insert the videos serially, all the videos get inserted to the playlist but it takes a long time. When I use multithreading more than half of the videos are missing in the end. How can I insert multiple videos quickly without losing any videos?

```
// Insert videos. 5 videos per asyncTask
List<List<YTVideo>> chunks = Lists.partition(videos, 5);
for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size(); i++) {
    videoAndPlaylistContainer container = new videoAndPlaylistContainer();
    container.playlistId = playlistId;
    List<YTVideo> chunk = chunks.get(i);
    container.videos = chunk;
    InsertPlayListItemTask insertPlaylistItemsTask = new InsertPlayListItemTask();
    runningTasks.add(insertPlaylistItemsTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,container));

}
```

.

```
 private class InsertPlayListItemTask extends AsyncTask<videoAndPlaylistContainer, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(videoAndPlaylistContainer... params) {
            videoAndPlaylistContainer container = params[0];
            List<YTVideo> videosChunk = container.videos;
            String playlistId = container.playlistId;
            for (int i = 0; i < videosChunk.size(); i++) {
                YTVideo video = videosChunk.get(i);
                String videoId = video.getId();
                long pos = video.getPosition();
                try {
                    ResourceId resourceId = new ResourceId();
                    resourceId.setKind("youtube#video");
                    resourceId.setVideoId(videoId);

                    PlaylistItemSnippet playlistItemSnippet = new PlaylistItemSnippet();
                    // playlistItemSnippet.setTitle("First video in the test playlist");
                    playlistItemSnippet.setPlaylistId(playlistId);
                    playlistItemSnippet.setResourceId(resourceId);
                    playlistItemSnippet.setPosition(pos);

                    PlaylistItem playlistItem = new PlaylistItem();
                    playlistItem.setSnippet(playlistItemSnippet);


                    YouTube.PlaylistItems.Insert playlistItemsInsertCommand =
                            youtube.playlistItems().insert("snippet", playlistItem);

                    playlistItemsInsertCommand.execute();

                    System.out.println("Inserted video: " + video);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

edit: videos.size() to chunks.size(). Removed insertedCount++;

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't look right...

```
for (int i = 0; i < videos.size(); i++) {
```

The `i` variable will grow based on the size of the `videos` collection, but you only ever use the `i` variable to access an element within the `chunks` collection here...

```
List<YTVideo> chunk = chunks.get(i);
```

I can't imagine why you don't (eventually) get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception, except maybe you're testing your code (so far) with fewer than 5 videos.

Comment: You're right that was an error. I forgot to change it while I was trying different things. the issue still remains even with that fix

Comment: I see.  Are you using the `insertedCount` variable for anything?  (AFAIK it will only ever reach the value of `chunks.size()`, or `5`).

Comment: Nope, that's left over from when I was inserting serially.

Comment: Is `YTVideo` a custom class?  (If so, can you add the source?)  How is `YTVideo.getPosition()` calculated?  What happens when a position is specified that's already occupied?